# How do I do the equivalent of TaskCompletionSource<nothing>?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I want to have a [EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle)-like Task where I await on it on one end, and then just set it to completed on the other end. [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) is almost what I want, but it requires me to pass a value. I could just use a dummy value, but before I do that I thought I'd see if there's a more correct solution.

The point is to be able to use [Task.WaitAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No. Use a dummy value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common scenario I've seen in source code is simply to create an empty `struct` which is equivalent to nothing. Or use a `bool` as dummy:

```
internal struct Void { }
```

And then:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Void>();
```

I've seen this common pattern in the [BCL source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,b43850570fcae163) as well:

```
// Special internal struct that we use to signify that we are not interested in
// a Task<VoidTaskResult>'s result.
internal struct VoidTaskResult { }
```

Comment: Or, possibly: `internal struct VoidTaskResult { public static readonly VoidTaskResult Value = default(VoidTaskResult); }`, so one can do `tcs.SetResult(VoidTaskResult.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 5, a non-generic [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource) class is available in .NET standard libraries.

```
public class TaskCompletionSource
```

It has exactly the same functionality with the [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) class, apart from the `TResult`.